# how to prevent chrome from changes the width of the input with min and max values

Tags: html, google-chrome

chrome by default changes the width of the input to fit the `min` and `max` values ,
as if it add a `size` attr. to it

how can I prevent chrome from doing this ?

https://jsfiddle.net/cobratst/apj75p7q/

Comment: Set width in css? No other way to get (almost) uniform form elements look in all browsers, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question here probably: [Styling HTML5 input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066436/styling-html5-input-type-number)

Simply use CSS to style your input as in the above question,  or apply inline styles:

```
<input style="width:50%;">
```