# How to change NumberInput widget width in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-widget

I'm trying to change the width of NumberInput and TextInput widgets:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.FloatField: {'widget': NumberInput(attrs={'size':'10'})},
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'10'})},
    }
```

It works good with TextInput widget but does not work with NumberInput widget.
How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "works good" ?

Comment: I mean it works for TextInput.

Answer (score 2):

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Elements of type "number" don't support form sizing attributes such as size. You'll have to resort to CSS to change the size of these controls.

Have you tried putting a class and create a css to fit the sizes?

It would look something like this:

```
models.FloatField: {'widget': NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-number'})},
```

And in css you add this:

```
.form-number {
width: 10pt;
}
```

Comment: No I did not try it.
I just think if it works with TextInput it should works with NumberInput as well...

Comment: Apparently [it doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066436/styling-html5-input-type-number).

Comment: I usually do not adjust appearances with widget. I just add class to fit everything into css later. I've never tested the size, so I can not tell you if it works with NumberInput.

Comment: Elements of type "number" don't support form sizing attributes such as size. You'll have to resort to CSS to change the size of these controls.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the width of your NumberInput at your form

```
class CreateBudgetItem(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BudgetModelItems
        fields = ('budget_model',)
        widgets = {
            'budget_item_description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 2, 'cols': 50}),
            'budget_item_item': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'size': 6}),
            'budget_item_quantity': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'size': 6}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `size`, you need to set `style` to change the width of [NumberInput()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#numberinput) as shown below:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {                              # Instead of 'size'
        models.FloatField: {'widget': NumberInput(attrs={'style':'width:10ch'})},
        models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size':'10'})},
    }
```