# Define the size for <input type="number">

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a simple HTML interface with `<input type="number">` in it. The problem is that the `<input>` element is taking too much space (It takes about 10 columns, but I only need two columns).

Because the input will never be more than two digits, I want to define as size of 2 characters for the `<input type="number">` element.

However the `width` attribute only works with `<input type="image">`, and alternatively the `size` attribute doesn't work with the `type` attribute set as `number`. What other alternatives are there? (preferably HTML, or maybe CSS, nothing else)

note:
sounds like there is a css solution, as given below, however just to be more clear, I must add this question is not about setting a max/min value to the `number` type of `input` element, rather the width. CSS, as given below, solved the problem, although I haven't seen an HTML solution, but that's fine enough for me. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling HTML5 input type number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066436/styling-html5-input-type-number)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input[type="number"] {
  width: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

`em` can be used to style the width of elements based on the font size. The only problem is that you will have to make the  element wider than two characters because the up and down arrows needs some space inside of the input box as well. Try readjusting the width to `2em` instead of `2.5em` and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

`width` should work. At least it works here on Firefox in the following snippet:

```css
input[type=number] {
  background: #fc9;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="number" name="x" value="23"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -4):

Ok, its pretty simple. all you have to use CSS to define a width.

`<input type="number" class="form-control">`

then

```
.form-control{
     display: block;
     width: 20%; //for two column
    }
```

and use some more css styles to make it gorgeous.